# Does the difference quotient of an absolut cont. funct. converge in L^1?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that $\mu$ is a finite Radon measure on the real line and $f$ is integrable wrt. $\mu$. Define

$F(x)=\int_{]\infty;t]}f(y)d\mu(y) $

Is the following statement true?

The functions $d_h:x\mapsto \frac{F(x+h)-F(x-h)}{\mu(]x-h,x+h])}$ converge in $L^1(d\mu)$ against f.

Remarks:

1. Could we replace the quotient by $\frac{F(x+h)-F((x-h)^-)}{\mu([x-h,x+h])}$?
2. This quotient would converge a.e against f by the differentiation theorem form measures. So if f would be  bounded the result is true. By approximation we could extend this result to $f \in L^p$ for p>1, whenever we can apply the Hardy–Littlewood maximal function theorem.

Comment: Split $f=g+u$ where $g$ is bounded (or even continuous) and $u$ has small $L^1$ norm. Estimate $\|d_hu\|_{L^1(\mu)}\le 3\|u\|_{L^1(\mu)}$. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. How could I mark the question as answered?